# How to make fluid box shaped divs?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I would like my UI bar to have square shaped buttons that decrease and increase fluidly in size. The idea is that no matter what responsive state my app is in, the buttons will always be square shaped.

Right now my nav buttons dimensions are always changing depending on the browser window width e.g.

[image]

I am using Foundation 5 but I see no function to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript.  Since you're using a fluid layout it would be the width that is the important number.  So if you use javascript you could target each box to force the height to equal the width of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide any code, so I can give you a exact answer.

But the standard practice to get this is to use the padding-top or padding bottom property.

This are vertical dimensions, but are related to the parent *width*, so doing something like

```
width: 5%;
padding: 0px;
height: 0px;
padding-top: 5%;
```

will give you always a square